# Rails - Inherited Resource - missing template in one environment only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inherited-resources

Question as above - I'm trying to create a new booking which happens fine in development, however the same code on the staging server gives me:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplatebooking_system/bookings#new
Missing template booking_system/bookings/new, booking_system/base/new, inherited_resources/base/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html].....
```

I can see it's trying to look for a template in the inherited resources folder but not finding one... I've googled and can't find anyone with a similar issue.. my controller code if its needed:

```
module BookingSystem
  class BaseController < InheritedResources::Base
  end
end

module BookingSystem
  class BookingsController < BaseController
     authorize_resource
  end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but have you checked that the file actually *exists* on production?? Maybe you've not pushed the branch / deployed it correctly?!

Comment: also can you indicate how your view folder look like? (`tree app/views` if you have `tree` installed)

Comment: In addition, to the above comments, be sure to show the file ownership and permissions, since these are likely to be more strictly enforced on a production box. What web  / application server are you using and which OS?